# Angular 4: Authguard(canActivate) in not blocking the url as it should, breaks the app blocking everything, no errors are thrown in console/browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I created this authguard but is not blocking the route when the user is logged out. The app auth workflow works fine, I use traditional sessions on the db in the backend, I verified the state of the auth service with chrome using Augury extension and the auth states set ok with the different operations so the problem is not there.

This is my **auth-guard.service.ts** service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
     return this.authService.isAuthenticated().map(isAuth => {
       console.log('is authenticated',isAuth);
            if (isAuth) {
                return true;
            }else{
                this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
                return Observable.of(false);
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            return Observable.of(false);
        });;
  }
}
```

This is my **authService** with the method isAuthenticated() which is used by the auth guard to block or not the route(I'm using publishReplay to catch the authState for 5 times to save some requests to the db since I didn't find a better way to check for user auth state, I just do a query and If the auth guard of the backend don't reject it then it means the session is still active returning a code 200:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnInit {
 userIsAuthenticated = new Subject();
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) { }

  private getHeaders(){
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Authorization','Bearer');
      return headers;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    //it starts as false to check with the server if the user is authenticated
    this.userIsAuthenticated.next(false);
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.getHeaders(), withCredentials: true });
      return this.http.get('http://someurl/api/sponsor/check/login',options)
        .map(response => {
          let res = response.json();
          console.log("response");
          if (res.code == 200) {
            this.userIsAuthenticated.next(true);
            return true;
          } else {
            this.userIsAuthenticated.next(false);
            return false;
          }
        }
      ).publishReplay(5);

  }



}
```

This is my **routing file**:

```
import { NgModule }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ActiveCampaignsComponent } from './dashboard/active-campaigns/active-campaigns.component';
import { HistoryCampaignsComponent } from './dashboard/history-campaigns/history-campaigns.component';
import { OverviewCampaignsComponent } from './dashboard/overview-campaigns/overview-campaigns.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: '', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component:SigninComponent},
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate:[AuthGuard],component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo:'dashboard/overview', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'overview', component: OverviewCampaignsComponent },
      { path: 'active', component: ActiveCampaignsComponent},
      { path: 'history', component: HistoryCampaignsComponent}
    ] }

]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{

}
```

As you can see the dashboard route is implementing this auth guard but it's not blocking anything and it has an unexpected behaviour blocking all the links if I add that line(this happens I logout and try to access by url to the dashboard route, it breaks the app yet no errors are seen in console, links don't respond after doing that). What seems to be the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "dashboard route is implementing this auth guard but it's not blocking anything"?  Because, you then go onto say that all the URLs are blocked when you log out, which is the behavior that should happen if a guard is working. So, why do you think that the guard isnt working?

Comment: I mean, if I try to access the dashboard by url without being logged in localhost:4200/dashboard, obviously the app refreshes and when I try to access the login and logout links everything gets frozen after the refresh, and I specified on the Authguard that I wanted to redirect the user to the login page if he was not authenticated, that gives me the idea that the guard is not working properly, any ideas??

Comment: without having context, some things to note: you shouldn't be returning Observable.of(false) in your AuthGuard - you should be returning: false. The Observable.of(false) is necessary for the catch handler, but not within the map function. Also, your http request is to a 'logout' url - are you sure that's correct?  Finally, you have a number of console.logs around. Based on that feedback, is the authentication code being called? which methods are being called?

Comment: Thank you very much for that last questions, it lead me to the answer. The code wasn't getting executed due to an unauthorized error being returned and not catched by the isAuthenticated method, so the guard code never got to execute. If I add the caching with publishReplay on isAuthenticated the code doesn't work, I have to hide components based on auth and I don't want to make one request per component I need to check auth status on( I have 3 components that are auth aware so I was doing publishReplay(3), but it doesn't work). Any ideas on where to read about that kind of solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you forgot to add your guard to Providers array in `AppModule`, also add `canActivate` after component name, you should have something similar code above.(This may be the problem why your Guard doesn't protect dashboard routes.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'dashboard', 
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not catching the error on authService on the isAuthenticated method after map, so the authGuard code didn't get executed due to the error being thrown before giving it a chance to execute, I removed the publishReplay(for caching) as well cause code didn't get executed after entering a guarded url, but I prefer to open another topic with the problem. Thanks :

**authService**:

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.getHeaders(), withCredentials: true });
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/check/login',options)
        .map(response => {
          let res = response.json();
          console.log("response");
          if (res.code == 200) {
            this.userIsAuthenticated.next(true);
            return true;
          }
        }
      ).catch((err)=>{
        //maybe add in the future if the code is 403 then send him to login otherwise send him elsewhere
        return Observable.of(false);
      });

  }
```

authGuard, I changed the return value in case of not being logged in from Observable.of(false) to just false(I don't think this was mandatory since the signature lets you return an Observable, but I just prefer to give full details of the solution to the problem:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
     return this.authService.isAuthenticated().map(isAuth => {
       console.log('is authenticated',isAuth);
            if (isAuth) {
                return true;
            }else{
                this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
                return false;
            }
        });
  }
```

There were no changes on routes file compared to what I previously posted.